# Training, Validation, Testing Batch Size Ratio

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, training-data

I'm doing transfer learning using Inception on Tensorflow, this is the training code that I followed : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/hub/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

At the bottom part of the code, we can specify the parameters according to our dataset. (there are **training, val, test percentage** and **training, val, test batch size**) 
Let's say I have a very large dataset (1 mil) and I already set the `training, validation, testing percentage` to **75:15:10**.

But I have no idea how to set the batch parameters correctly :

- train_batch_size
- validation_batch_size
- test_batch_size

For now, I set the `train_batch_size` to 64, do I need to set the same value for `validation_batch_size`? Or should it be bigger or smaller than the `train_batch_size`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can follow the advice from the other answers for the dataset split ratio. However, the batch size has absolutely *nothing* to do with how you've split your datasets.

The batch size determines how many training examples are processed in parallel for training/inference. The batch size at training time can affect how fast and how well your training converges. You can find a discussion of this effect [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/tradeoff-batch-size-vs-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neural-network). Thus, for `train_batch_size`, it's worth picking a batch size that is neither too small nor too large (as discussed in the previously linked discussion). For some applications, using the largest possible training batches can actually be desirable, but in general, you select it through experiments and validation.

However, for `validation_batch_size` and `test_batch_size`, you should pick the largest batch size that your hardware can handle without running out of memory and crashing. Finding this is usually a simple trial and error process. The larger your batch size at inference time, the faster it will be, since more inputs can be processed in parallel.

EDIT: Here's an [additional useful link](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html) (Pg. 276) for the training batch size trade-off from Goodfellow et al's deep learning book.

Comment: The validation step is usually very fast so you don't lose that much by picking a suboptimal batch size.

Answer (score 0):

So, the train, test and validation sets will be part of your main dataset. 
Let's assume your dataset has `x` observations (i.e. x rows)
When you do a `train, validation and test spilts` you split it by the percentage amount specified by you.
**And the sum of the percentages should add up to `100%`**. 
Therefore when you do a `75:15:10` split. It means that the data of `x` rows will get split into `x * .75 rows` as train set. Of the remaining `25% -- y` of data, `y * .15` will be validation set and the rest will test set. 
As you can see they all add up to `100%`. 
It is generally a best practise to use a train, test split of `75:25`. 
To learn more about why they are important read this [Medium Article](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-validation-and-test-sets-72cb40cba9e7).

Comment: Okay,so you are saying that my split is already good right? What about the batch size split?

Comment: See I don't think you understand them well. It's better you read that article about what are training sets, test sets etc. There is nothing called batch size split!

Answer (score -2):

> Let's say I have a very large dataset (1 mil) and I already set the training, validation, testing percentage to `75:15:10`.

On very large dataset like you mentioned you can go with `98:1:1`.

Comment: Really? I didn't know about that. Do you have any idea how to set the batch size as well?

Comment: Via experiment.